# What can I do in Unity3D to optimize the way I'm calculating contrast of a texture2D?

Tags: unity, c#, image-processing, image-effects

I have this contrast script right now in Unity:

```
public void ApplyContrast(string contrast)
    {
        try
        {
            double contrastD = Convert.ToDouble(contrast);

            //Make an empty Texture the same same as the original 
            bitmapImage = new Texture2D(imgTexture.width, imgTexture.height);

            if (contrastD < -100) contrastD = -100;
            if (contrastD > 100) contrastD = 100;
            contrastD = (100.0 + contrastD) / 100.0;
            contrastD *= contrastD;
            Color color;

            //Access each pixel in the image (with three values per pixel (R,G,B) 
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImage.width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bitmapImage.height; j++)
                {
                    //get the pixel from the original image 
                    color = (imgTexture as Texture2D).GetPixel(i, j);

                    //Alpha value
                    double pA = color.a;

                    //Red 
                    double pR = color.r;
                    pR -= 0.5; //subtract 0.5 
                    pR *= contrastD;
                    pR += 0.5;
                    if (pR < 0) pR = 0;
                    if (pR > 255) pR = 255;

                    //Green
                    double pG = color.g;
                    pG -= 0.5;
                    pG *= contrastD;
                    pG += 0.5;
                    if (pG < 0) pG = 0;
                    if (pG > 255) pG = 255;

                    //Blue
                    double pB = color.b;
                    pB -= 0.5;
                    pB *= contrastD;
                    pB += 0.5;
                    if (pB < 0) pB = 0;
                    if (pB > 255) pB = 255;

                    //Set the new image's pixel to the contrast version from the new color object  
                    bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, j, new Color((float)pR, (float)pG, (float)pB, (float)pA));
                }
            }

            //Apply all SetPixel changes
            bitmapImage.Apply();

            //Connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to 
            Image.renderer.material.mainTexture = bitmapImage as Texture;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Item(ex);
        }
    }
```

and my brightness is:

```
public void AdjustBrightness(string brightness)
    {
        int brightnessInt = Convert.ToInt32(brightness);
        int mappedBrightness = (51 * brightnessInt) / 10 - 255;
        //Make an empty Texture the same same as the original 
        bitmapImage = new Texture2D(imgTexture.width, imgTexture.height);

        if (mappedBrightness < -255) mappedBrightness = -255;
        if (mappedBrightness > 255) mappedBrightness = 255;
        Color32 color;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImage.width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmapImage.height; j++)
            {
                color = (imgTexture as Texture2D).GetPixel(i, j);
                int cR = (int)color.r + mappedBrightness;
                int cG = (int)color.g + mappedBrightness;
                int cB = (int)color.b + mappedBrightness;

                if (cR < 0) cR = 0;
                if (cR > 255) cR = 255;

                if (cG < 0) cG = 0;
                if (cG > 255) cG = 255;

                if (cB < 0) cB = 0;
                if (cB > 255) cB = 255;

                bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, j,
    new Color(cR/255f, cG/255f, cB/255f));
            }
        }
        //Apply all SetPixel changes
        bitmapImage.Apply();

        //Connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to 
        Image.renderer.material.mainTexture = bitmapImage as Texture;
    }
```

However this is slow and the brightness/contrast doesn't look right.

Can I use Image Effects in Unity Pro or something else to manipulate brightness/contrast for my uploaded Texture2D image?

I have a slider with values from 0% to 100% and I am adjusting the brightness/contrast using the above scripts and double checking the input ranges match the algorithm above.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest optimization you can do is to calculate this on the graphics card -- one way to do that is to use [Graphics.Blit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html) and a shader to do the brightness/contrast effect. The result has to be a RenderTexture, but if you need the result in a Texture2D, you can use Texture2D.ReadPixels to copy the data from a RenderTexture to a Texture2D, in about [3 lines of code, apparently](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9969/convert-a-rendertexture-to-a-texture2d.html):

`RenderTexture.active = myRenderTexture;
 myTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, myRenderTexture.width, myRenderTexture.height), 0, 0);
 myTexture2D.Apply();`

As long as you're using Unity 5, you can do this without the Pro version.

Comment: I have the Unity Pro version for 4.3, Can I still do this? So, if I create a shader, do I attach it to gameobject/prefab that contains my texture2D? The shader would have the formulas for brightness and contrast? Are my brightness/contrast formulas alright? Is there a significant different with how I'm doing it above vs. lookup table with input/output curves for brightness/contrast?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. This might be a try-it-and-see situation. Graphics.Blit takes the material you want to use as a third parameter, and the material has the shader.

Comment: Okay btw what is myRenderTexture in this example and myTexture2D?